# Add www to the Root Site in WP Multisite Network

Tags: multisite, url-rewriting, site-url

I have a WordPress (Latest version) based website with Multisite Network Enabled. For example, the domain is `example.com`. So, my root site is `example.com` and my subsite is `blog.example.com`. But I want my root site as `www.example.com`. To do so, I've taken 4 steps:

Modified `.htaccess` file. Added the code below:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301]
```

Modified `wp-config.php`:

```
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'www.example.com');
```

Modified MySQL table `wp_site`. Old data: `domain: example.com`. New Data:

```
domain: www.example.com
```

Modified MySQL table `wp_sitemeta`. Old data: `siteurl: example.com`. New Data:

```
siteurl: www.example.com
```

But unfortunately, it didn't work. What to do?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I know, that is not possible with Multisite. Go through the docs, If I remember correctly, that is a downsite of WPMS.

Comment: Oh no! This is a huge problem then! BTW, thanks a lot.